# How do I add a System V filter using the cups API?

Tags: c, linux, printing, cups

I need to programmatically add a printer to cups that has a System V filter installed.  Right now I am using the following code to create the request to add the printer:

```
pstRequest = ippNew();

pstRequest->request.op.operation_id = CUPS_ADD_PRINTER;
pstRequest->request.any.request_id  = 1;

ippAddString(pstRequest, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_CHARSET, "attributes-charset", NULL, "us-ascii");
ippAddString(pstRequest, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_LANGUAGE, "attributes-natural-language", NULL, "en");

ippAddString(pstRequest, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_NAME, "requesting-user-name", NULL, cupsUser());
ippAddString(pstRequest, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_URI, "device-uri", NULL, szUri);
ippAddString(pstRequest, IPP_TAG_OPERATION, IPP_TAG_URI, "printer-uri", NULL, szPrinterUri);
ippAddInteger(pstRequest, IPP_TAG_PRINTER, IPP_TAG_ENUM, "printer-state", IPP_PRINTER_IDLE);
ippAddBoolean(pstRequest, IPP_TAG_PRINTER, "printer-is-accepting-jobs", true);
```

For the sake of conversaion:

```
szUri        = "serial:/dev/pts/12?baud=2400+bits=7+parity=none+flow=none";
szPrinterUri = "ipp://localhost/printers/myptr";
```

This appears to correctly add the printer to the cups system because I can then send print to it using the following command:

```
lp -d myptr test.print
```

My first thought was to just copy the file that I wanted to use as the filter into the `/etc/cups/interfaces` directory and call it `myptr`.  I did this, gave it the correct user, group, and permissions, and it didn't seem to work.  I even tried sticking a `sleep 60` at the front of the script and it never showed up in `ps`.

I've tried adding the printer using `lpadmin` as follows and it works correctly:

```
lpadmin -h localhost -p myptr2 -v "serial:/dev/pts/12?baud=2400+bits=7+parity=none+flow=none" -i /tmp/my.serial.filter
```

I have to call `cupsaccept` and `cupsenable` afterward, but the printer works and it sends the print through my filter.  `lpadmin` correctly copies the `my.serial.filter` file from `/tmp` into `/etc/cups/interfaces` and names it `myptr2`, just as I did in my program, and, for the life of me, I cannot find any reference to the filter in any of the cups configuration files that makes me think I'm missing a step.  Nevertheless, the `myptr2` printer that I add with `lpadmin` works correctly and the `myptr` printer that I add using the API, while it *does* print, does *not* print through the filter.

Among the various Google searches I have made, I have read through the [CUPS Implementation](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/spec-ipp.html) and the [HTTP and IPP APIs Documentation](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/api-httpipp.html), and the closest that I have come to was that, in the former, there is a comment for the [CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer Operation](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/spec-ipp.html#CUPS_ADD_MODIFY_PRINTER)that reads:

> The CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer request can optionally be followed by a PPD file or System V interface script to be used for the printer. The "ppd-name" attribute overrides any file that is attached to the end of the request with a local CUPS PPD file.

This led me to try using

```
ippAddString(pstRequest, IPP_TAG_PRINTER, IPP_TAG_NAME, "ppd-name", NULL, szFilter);
```

with szFilter set to both `"/tmp/my.serial.filter"` and `"/etc/cups/interfaces/myptr"` (in separate tests, of course), but to no avail.

Can anyone tell me where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got ahold of the source to lpadmin from the cups source repository and the answer was much easier than I was trying to make it.  Apparently, I did not include enough of my source in the initial posting.  After the code snippet from above, I was calling the following:

```
pstHttpServer = httpConnectEncrypt("localhost", ippPort(), cupsEncryption());
pstResponse   = cupsDoFileRequest(pstHttpServer, pstRequest, "/admin/", NULL);
ippDelete(pstResponse);
httpClose(pstHttpServer);
```

(with applicable error checking, of course)

The answer to my question is in the `NULL` pointer that I was passing as the fourth argument to `cupsDoFileRequest`.  As noted above, "[t]he CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer request can optionally be followed by a PPD file or System V interface script."  I hadn't tied the two together, but that sentence refers to the fourth argument of `cupsDoFileRequest` in which, if I place the path of my filter, `"/tmp/my.serial.filter"`, the request succeeds and `my.serial.filter` gets correctly copied into `/etc/cups/interfaces` as `myptr`, after which all of my print to `myptr` goes through the filter as expected.

Thus, the final solution is to change the `pstResponse` line above as follows:

```
pstResponse   = cupsDoFileRequest(pstHttpServer, pstRequest, "/admin/", "/tmp/my.serial.filter");
```